# Using if statement in c# for SQL

Tags: c#, sql, if-statement

I'm trying to writing a basic c# program that read datas from SQL and writes results on 3 textboxes and a label. Here is my code;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace PLAKA
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TESTDB;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Project where ID = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
            textBox3.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            textBox4.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();


            SqlDataAdapter oks = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Project where Status = 'YES'", con);

            if (oks)
            {
                label1.Text = "POSITIVE";
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = "NEGATIVE";

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm writing ID number and see the informations of this ID on text boxes in my first part of my code and this works perfectly

All i need that when value in the 'Status' raw is "YES", my program writes "POSITIVE", other else writes 'NEGATIVE' on label1

Meanwhile Status information writes on Textbox3.

For this code i got this error message: "Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter' to 'bool'

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking `dt.Rows[0]["Status"]` ?  Issuing a second query will get you records that don't match your original ID.

Comment: status row for textbox is dt.Rows[0][2]

Comment: You need to call `Fill()` on the `oks` SqlDataAdapter, you haven't actually returned any data yet.

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: @markpsmith how can i call Fill() on oks? Should i write oks.Fill(dt)? and how can i write if statement for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your **If condition** is wrong.

use this.

```
SqlDataAdapter oks = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Project where Status = 'YES'", con);

oks.fill(dataSet)

if (dataSet.Tables["Table"].Rows.Count > 1)
 {
    label1.Text = "POSITIVE";
  }
   else
  {
    label1.Text = "NEGATIVE";

  }
```

Comment: I Updated my code like you said but i got these error codes now. Error 2 'System.Data.DataSet' does not contain a definition for 'tables' and Error 1 'System.Data.DataSet' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: same here. there are problems about DataSet and Tables commands in the oks.fill(DataSet) and if (DataSet.Tables....)